# audio replay software with automatic play pause cycle

Tags: audio

I'm looking for a software to write down notes from a recording (taken with Samsung Android Smartphone and moved/converted to PC)

(I use Win 8.1, but I can also access Win 7 or Ubuntu.)

for example:

- 5 sec play
- 5 sec pause
- 1 sec rewind

and then a new automatic cycle:

- 5 sec play
- ...

Is there a software which will do more or less like this?

(If not, maybe there is a solution to do it with Audacity...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [Express Scribe Transcription Software](http://www.nch.com.au/scribe/) to transcribe audio notes previously.

- Free for non-commercial home use
- Supports Windows 8 (though I've only tested Win7)
- Supported audio formats: MP3, WAV, WMA, AIFF, MP2, VOX

You can define global hot-key's within the application, allowing you to start, stop, rewind, +/- 5 secs, speed up/slow down playback etc. without leaving the text editor you're typing the notes into. After finishing transcribing a recording, you can also mark it as 'Done' to remove it from the list of dictations to organise your workflow a bit.

I'm not sure if it matches your 'play pause rewind'-cycle requirement, but may be a good fit for your needs.

**EDIT**

You could achieve 'play pause rewind'-cycle functionality with the above application if you used a macro scripting language like [autohotkey](http://ahkscript.org/) to automate the required key presses. I was interested in it myself so I've written such a script and you can use it if you like. It's available on GitHub here:

https://github.com/a-henderson/autohotkey-transcription-audio-loop

Naturally it's not ideal to run two programs, but this does work :)

Comment: Well, it's a nice tool, however it would be very useful if it happens automatically without pressing the FN buttons. Do you also know an android app which could do this cycle? Currently I'm using "Smart AudioBook Player" with manual rewind function.

Comment: @laminin nah I don't know of an android app that would do it. I was curious if I could make the software I linked do what you wanted with an external script though, and I believe I've got something that works. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Your tool made with autohotkey is very useful. Thank you a lot for your work! For me it would be nice to exchange F9 (play) with F3 and F7 (rewind) with F5 (because I redesigned yesterday my keyboard layout with symbols). Is it possible to replace this in the  ahk file with an Text-Editor and then save the modified ahk file somehow as a exe file?

Comment: Yup, that's quite an easy change to make. I've swapped those function keys around and you can download an updated .exe here:  
http://we.tl/A2dgcXpPTl  
If you'd like to play around yourself, download and install [autohotkey](http://ahkscript.org/), download the .ahk file from [GitHub](https://github.com/a-henderson/autohotkey-transcription-audio-loop) then open it in a text editor and change the F numbers on lines 37, 46 & 48. Save the changes to the .ahk, then use the 'Convert .ahk to .exe' script that comes with the autohotkey installation to convert it.

Comment: I use now your modified exe file. That's exactly what I've looked for. Thank you very much.

Comment: @laminin Awesome, glad it works for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is a browser-based solution available at Jotengine website: https://jotengine.com/diy

The tool inludes an auto-rewind function with preset lengths of 10s play, 5s pause, 5s re-wind.

There are also shortcuts for changing playback speed, inserting timestamps and rewinding or skipping forward 5s.

It is free to use, and worked all right for me.